# Jackson Jersey JSON

Tags: java, json, jersey, jackson

I'm trying to use Jersey and Jackson (although any other way of doing JSON demarshalling works) to get this into my system in some form (be it POJO or some other representation).

Basically I only need the data section.  I was trying to use GenericTypes with lists, but this is a nested list and I'm just not sure what to do.  Lots of kudos for help and I really appreciate it!

```
{
    "total": 4,
    "data": [
        {
            "descriptor": "",
            "multiInstance": false,
            "active": false
        },
        {
            "descriptor": "Apparel",
            "multiInstance": true,
        },
        {
            "descriptor": "abcd123",
            "multiInstance": false,

        },
        {
            "descriptor": "abcd",
            "multiInstance": false,
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the class I'm trying to use.  I need a list of the class.

```
public class customObject {

@JsonProperty(value = "descriptor")
private String descriptor;
@JsonProperty(value = "multiInstance")
private Boolean multiInstance;

//getters and setters
}
```

Edit:

I'm using it in here.

CustomObjectResponse WDCOResponse =
                resource
                .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .header("Authorization", getToken()).get(WDCOResponse.class);

But it's still not working.

Edit2:
Figured this out!  Thanks to everyone.  :)

I had to add annotation to tell it to ignore if something wasn't found, some of the JSON I'm getting back was not fully-formed in that not all fields were absolutely neccesary.

Comment: Did you try using http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you the object you provided is what you are passing to your controller, then you will need one more wrapper object to contain the list like this:

```
public class CustomRequest {

    @JSonProperty(value = "total");
    private Integer total;

    @JsonProperty(value = "data")
    private List<CustomObject> data;

    // getters/setters

}


public class CustomObject {

    @JsonProperty(value = "descriptor")
    private String descriptor;

    @JsonProperty(value = "multiInstance")
    private Boolean multiInstance;

    // getters/setters
}
```

Then your controller will just have annotations that show that the RequestBody is the CustomRequest class:

```
@Controller
public class JSONController {

    @RequestMapping(value="sendData")
        public @ResponseBody CustomResponse sendData(
            @RequestBody CustomRequest request)
    {
    return null;
    }

}
```

If you are still getting errors, please provide detailed error or problem.  Thanks!

Comment: So i'm actually trying to format JSON information that is coming from another API.  I'm building a client API right now.  I'm doing what you have but it's not working, I just jump out.  I'm assuming there's an exception so I'm going to look at this by adding a exception catcher that will print out.

Answer (score 0):

You'd use POJO like:

```
public class Response {
  int count;
  List<customObject> data;
}
```

and access the data from there:

```
for (customObject ob : response.data) {
   // process ig
}
```